# Obj-C editor with a bad MVC pattern, how to clean this up?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, model-view-controller

[image]

I've been working on a game engine in Obj-C and decided to build an editor for it as well in Obj-C. This is how I've done it for now, but I would like to get rid of all the "glue code" and follow "best practises". To much time is being spent on the "glue code" and the code base is getting very large to maintain with objects depending on each other and keeping referances. A typical old-school scenario :-)

The View contains a lot of options i.e. checkboxes, sliders & textfields.

1) When the "Stars" number is changed to 2000, an action is sent to the Controller.

2) Controller verifies the input, numeric textfields have a number formatter but text input for file names or other names the input is verified by running some code to check if the name is valid.

3) The number is stars (2000) is sent to the next layer, the Game Engine Scene (which has a Starfield Object member).

4) The Game Engine Scene applies the new amount of stars to the Starfield Object member.

*) If the number of stars changes inside of the Game Engine Scene or the Starfield Object, a call is made up to the Controller which then updates the UI textfield.

How can I make this right and more efficient, get rid of all the glue code for all the options I can set yet keep is simple and clean?
Do I need to modify the Game Engine as well to make it work better with the editor and its UI?

I think I should aim for something like this, what do you think?
Use bindings, KVO etc. ?

[image]

Example Code: Assume that I change the number of stars in the textfield and this gets called.

```
// in the Controller class
- (IBAction)starfieldAmountChanged: (id)sender
{
    const NSInteger numOfStars = [sender integerValue];
    [mGameEngineTestScene setStarfieldAmount: numOfStars];
}

// in the Game Engine test scene class
- (void)setStarfieldAmount: (NSInteger)newAmountOfStars
{
    [mStarfield setAmountOfStars: newAmountOfStars];
}

- (NSInteger)getStarfieldAmount
{
    return [mStarfield getAmountOfStars];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Understand that "MVC" is largely a fiction, rarely achieved in practice.

Comment: Since you haven't posted any actual code, it's hard to suggest ways to clean it up. What is the glue code and why do you think it's bad?

Comment: The glue code is bad because it's only sending data from the UI down to the Starfield object and vice versa. UI->Controller->Game Engine->Starfield